# SQL UNION performance

Tags: sql, union, tableau-api, vertica

I am using three UNIONs in my sql query. The query takes a lot of time. Is there any other faster alternative to it? My database is Vertica and I've written the query in Tableau.
The Select Query looks like -

```
(select A,B,C from (select fun(X) as A, B,C,D from table1 where condition1 group by B,C,D)alias where condition2)
UNION 
(select A,B,C from (select fun(X) as A, B,C,D from table1 where condition1 group by B,C,D)alias where condition3)
]
UNION
[
(select A,B,C from (select fun(X) as A, B,C,D from table1 where condition1 group by B,C,D)alias where condition4) 
UNION
(select A,B,C from (select fun(X) as A, B,C,D from table1 where condition1 group by B,C,D)alias where condition5)
```

Comment: are you using `*` in the Query ??

Comment: How does the query look like?

Comment: (
( select A,B,C from table1 where condition1) UNION (select A,B,C from table1 where condition 2)
) UNION
 ( (select A,B,C from table1 where condition3)UNION (select A,B,C from table1 where condition4)
)

Comment: Can you use UNION ALL instead? (That's what people want most of the time...)

Comment: I see. Okay I will try using UNION ALL and see if it  improves the performance 
@jarlh

Comment: The other thing to try is to run the query directly in Vertica. If the query takes the same amount of time to run as in Tableau, then it's not a Tableau issue.

Comment: I was running the query in vertica itself. @jarlh I tried using UNION ALL instead, it improved the performance a bit, the excution time reduced by 50%. Thanks 
Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Show us the SELECT, and table definitions. Approx number of rows. What about statistics?

Comment: @jarlh i have edited the question and included what the select query looks like. Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just do "select A,B,C from (select fun(X) as A, B,C,D from table1 where condition1 group by B,C,D)alias where (condition2) or (condition3) or (condition4) or (condition5)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNION ALL performs better than UNION since the database server does not have to eliminate duplicate rows which can be costly. Usually UNION ALL is what you want.

Also, it looks like you could just combine all your outermost where conditions using OR which ought to simplify the query to the point where you don't even need a UNION or UNION ALL